# Erro de Sintaxe usando ReactJS - SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, react, syntax-error

Foi desenvolvida uma calculadora utilizando reactjs, a princípio ela cumpre o propósito. O problema: ao realizar uma operação do tipo 05+1, a calculadora retorna o erro mencionado no titulo da pergunta.

Pesquisei sobre e descobri que o react utiliza 'strict mode' para otimizar a performance da aplicação dessa forma algumas sintaxes podem mudar, bem como más praticas podem ser traduzidas em um erro para não comprometer seu produto final.

Estou utilizando a função eval() para realizar o cálculo das expressões.

```
        if(value == '='){
        try{
            return document.getElementById('Screen').textContent = eval(document.getElementById('Screen').textContent)
        } catch(a){

            return document.getElementById('Screen').textContent = 'Error' + a
        }
    }
```

Por último deixo uma versão ativa do projeto no github

[Calculadora React](https://gabriecgaldino.github.io/calcreact/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia Gabriel, o problema é que quando usamos um `0` na frente de qualquer número, o `node` inseri um número de base `octal` ao invés de `decimal` então ele diz que escrever um número octal de maneira literal não é permitida.

Para resolver o problema você pode converter usando um `parseFloat`. Eu no seu caso não computaria o `0` se não for acompanhado por uma `,` logo em seguida.

Comment: Olá Breno, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Realmente sua resposta resolveu meu problema, minha solução foi implementar uma verificação do numero a cada clique e dai se o numero começar com 0 não importa o restante ele realiza a conversão, claro antes ele verifica se trata-se de um double pra depois seguir na conversão. Eu pessoalmente entendo 05 como um inteiro então estou convertendo em int. Mesmo assim muito obrigado.